# targetTouches.pageX has a big shift on Android 4.0.4 and 4.2

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, touch

I have a big problem and cannot know the reasons.

I use cordova 2.7, jquerymobile1.2

I develop a draw app and use ( e.targetTouches[0].pageX ) and  ( e.changedTouches[0].pageX ).

On Android 4.0.3 and 4.1 it works good.
But on Android 4.0.4 and 4.2 , it cause a big shift(by minus), like you draw only on the left top quarter of page. Numbers are returned correct and context of canvas has correct wodth and height of device, but this shift i cannot know its reasons.

please, any help ?

Comment: I tested on different devices, It works on HTC onex and Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.7. But doesn't on Samsung Note1, Note2 and S2. Is resolution of device or pixel density (pixels/points per inch) is the reason ?, if yes, how can we resolve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, may help any one.
I make canvas width 100% in css, that make scale issue on some devices, this scale ratio is related to device, so it change from one to another.
I removed it, and shifted issue is solved.

I hope that help any one else.